# Search Input Field to search a JavaScript Array - How to Validate an Empty Input Box

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation, input, textfield

I created a JavaScript array and used a search input field box to search the array to return a matching result if found or return a "not found" result if no match.

The search results work fine, but the form validation code I used does not work. In fact it seems to be ignored or completely nullified by the rest of the script.

What happens is when the input box is left blank and submitted, the result is the same as a wrong match, but with no value between the single quotes.

Instead, I need to create a validation script to first check if the input box is blank, and if blank, tell the user that some input is required. Of course, if not blank the rest of the script works as described.

Any suggestions?

Here is the code I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Test Search Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" action="input" onsubmit="return validate();">
<fieldset>
<input id="formInput" name="formInput" type="text" placeholder="Type Code Number Here" required/>
</fieldset>
</form>
<input id="searchBtn" type="submit" value="Submit">
</body>
</html>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var data = [{
    code: "2222",
    value: "$10.00"   
}, {
    code: "3333",
    value: "$30.00"
}, {
    code: "4444",
    value: "$50.00"
}, {
    code: "5555",
    value: "$100.00"
}, {
    code: "1111",
    value: "$300.00"
}, {
    code: "7777",
    value: "$500.00"
}, {
    code: "8888",
    value: "$1,000.00"
}, {
    code: "9999",
    value: "$3,000.00"
} ];

//Script to validate an empty input box
function validate()
{
var ch = document.getElementById('formInput');
if(ch.value === '')
{
alert('You Must Enter A Code Number First.');
return false;
}
}

//Script to search array for a match 
document.getElementById("searchBtn").addEventListener('click', function() {
    var formInput = document.getElementById("formInput").value,
        foundItem = null; //we'll store the matching value here

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].code == formInput) {
            foundItem = data[i];
            break; //we've found a match, no sense to continue
       }
    }

    if (foundItem) {
        alert("Jewellery Code # '" + foundItem.code + "' Value: " + foundItem.value);
    } else {
        alert("Code Number: '" + formInput + "' Was Not Found");
    }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not moving the `validate` function into your other `click event`?

```js
var data = [{
  code: "2222",
  value: "$10.00"
}, {
  code: "3333",
  value: "$30.00"
}, {
  code: "4444",
  value: "$50.00"
}, {
  code: "5555",
  value: "$100.00"
}, {
  code: "1111",
  value: "$300.00"
}, {
  code: "7777",
  value: "$500.00"
}, {
  code: "8888",
  value: "$1,000.00"
}, {
  code: "9999",
  value: "$3,000.00"
}];



//Script to search array for a match 
document.getElementById("searchBtn").addEventListener('click', function() {
  var formInput = document.getElementById("formInput").value,
    foundItem = null; //we'll store the matching value here

  if (formInput === '') {
    alert('You Must Enter A Code Number First.');
    return false;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].code == formInput) {
      foundItem = data[i];
      break; //we've found a match, no sense to continue
    }
  }

  if (foundItem) {
    alert("Jewellery Code # '" + foundItem.code + "' Value: " + foundItem.value);
  } else {
    alert("Code Number: '" + formInput + "' Was Not Found");
  }

});
```

```html
<form method="get" action="input">
  <fieldset>
    <input id="formInput" name="formInput" type="text" placeholder="Type Code Number Here" required/>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<input id="searchBtn" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Much Thanks, that worked. I don't know why I did not see that. I was likely thinking I could not insert the validate function there. I guess nothing ventured, nothing gained.